# Was bedeutet "Bis neulig" in diesem Satz

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In einem Forum habe ich diesen Ausdruck gesehen aber ich habe nicht verstanden, was es bedeuten soll. Ich weiß nicht ob er falsch geschrieben ist oder ein Ausdruck in einem Dialekt ist.

Der Ausdruck ist;

> Nochmals Dank und **bis neulig!**

Was bedeuet **bis neulig** hier?

Comment: JFTR: Volker Pispers’ Standardbühnenprogramm seit 2002 hieß „… bis neulich“.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Neulig* wird sehr oft falsch geschrieben und damit ist fast immer **neulich** gemeint. Neulich ist ein Adverb und beschreibt zum Beispiel ein Ereignis, welches erst kürzlich (in Vergangenheit) aufgetreten ist.

Durch das **bis** hat dein Ausdruck jedoch, in genau **diesem** Zusammenhang, eine komplett andere Bedeutung. Denn der Ausdruck steht so nämlich für eine Verabschiedung und bedeutet so etwas wie:

> 1. Bis dann, wir sehen uns!
> 2. Wir sehen uns, tschüss.

Im gängigen und normalen Sprachgebrauch versteht man unter *bis neulich* aber, dass man bis kürzlich zum Beispiel einen Fehler nicht finden oder einen geplanten Einkauf erledigen konnte.

Comment: Ich hab zwar vermutet, dass mit *neulig neulich* gemeint ist, hab mir aber auch *bis neulich* auch keinen Reim machen können. Danke für die Antwort =)

Comment: Anmerkung: "Falsch" ist immer relativ zu den gesellschaftlichen Kreisen innerhalb eines Zeitraums (Da die Sprache sich ständig weiterentwickelt). Hier findet man eine Abweichung vom Standard. Nun soll man erst fragen, wer den Standard geschrieben hat, und zu welchen gesellschaftlichen Kreisen gehört er, und wann wurde der Standard geschrieben?  Rhetorisch natürlich.

Answer (score -1):

Ja, natürlich isses falsch geschrieben, meist von Norddeutschsprachverweigerern.

> 'Bis neulich' greift einerseits auf das nächste Treffen vor, andererseits auf das 'neuliche' Treffen zurück.

Man verwendet es, wenn man sich nicht häufig sieht, sondern eher unverhofft über den Weg läuft. (veraltet, sonst disrespektabel)

Comment: Was sind denn bitte »Norddeutschsprachverweigerer«?